# Multiple Nested Forms with Default/Set Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have to rebuild a form in Rails that looks like this:

[image]

What you're looking at is a student who can have many grades (or school years) and for each grade (or school year), you can add assessments. There are three assessments (beginning, mid, and final) and each one will have a set amount of subjects. I get the subjects that are available at the school they're in so that value can update/change but I only ever want there to be the subjects taught in the school. Users should not be able to "Add a Subject"... I want to define them like you see above.

My question is, how do I achieve this? I have it working so I can add an unlimited amount of grades (or school years) to a student but I can't figure out how to seamlessly add another nested form categorized by assessment for each grade with all the subjects pre-set under each assessment. Models are below:

```
Class Student < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :school
  has_many :student_grades, inverse_of: :student, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :student_grades, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  validates :status, presence: true
  validates :school_id, presence: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :middle_name, presence: false
  validates :last_name, presence: true

  enum :status => [:active, :applying, :graduated, :expelled]

end

class StudentGrade < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :computer, optional: true
  has_many :student_grade_subject_assessments, inverse_of: :student_grade, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :student_grade_subject_assessments, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  validates :student_id, presence: true
  validates :school_year, presence: true
  validates :grade, presence: true
  validates :computer_id, presence: false

end

class StudentGradeSubjectAssessment < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :student_grade
  belongs_to :subject

  validates :student_grade_id, presence: true
  validates :subject_id, presence: true
  validates :assessment_type, presence: true
  validates :percentage, presence: false
  validates :comments, presence: false
  validates :plan, presence: false

  enum :assessment_type => [:beginning_assessment, :mid_term_assessment, :final_assessment]

end
```

`_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@student, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="student-profile">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :last_name, 'Last Name' %><br>
              <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :first_name, 'First Name' %><br>
              <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :middle_name, 'Middle Name' %><br>
              <%= f.text_field :middle_name, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :school_id %><br>
              <%= f.collection_select :school_id, School.all.order(:name), :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose..."}, {class: 'form-control'} %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="grades">
        <%= f.fields_for :student_grades do |student_grade| %>
            <%= render 'student_grade_fields', :f => student_grade %>
        <% end %>
        <div class='links'>
          <%= link_to_add_association 'Add School Year', f, :student_grades, class: "btn btn-success" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit "Save Student", class: "btn btn-success" %>

<% end %>
```

`_student_grade_fields.html.erb` just contains my fields for the corresponding model but that's also where I'd be putting the form for `StudentGradeSubjectAssessment`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want something like this:

```
@student.student_grades.each do |grade|
  ...year, grade, computer stuff for the grade

  grade.student_grade_subject_assessments.where(assessment_type: :beginning_assessment).each do |assessment|
    ...stuff for each beginning assessment per subject
  end

  grade.student_grade_subject_assessments.where(assessment_type: :middle_assessment).each do |assessment|
    ...stuff for each middle assessment per subject
  end

  grade.student_grade_subject_assessments.where(assessment_type: :end_assessment).each do |assessment|
    ...stuff for each final assessment per subject
  end
end
```

You could also save yourself the multiple queries for each type of assessment by grouping the one query by assessment type like this:

```
grade.student_grade_subject_assessments.group_by(:assessment_type)
```

This will produce a hash where the keys are the assessment types and the values are arrays of all of the subjects for that assessment type (already scoped by grade). Here's a [doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) with an example.